# How to specify AndroidAnnotations source generation directory for maven?

Tags: android, maven, android-annotations, android-maven-plugin

In the document describing setting up maven for AA (http://www.ashokgelal.com/2012/12/setting-up-intellij-idea-12-with-maven-actionbarsherlock-roboelectric-androidannotations/) there's no option to configure the source generation directory (where e.g. MyActivity_ is generated). Documents that explain setting up Maven+IntelliJ suggest to add annotation processor to the IntelliJ's compiler options, but what if I want to use only maven for compiling? The default placement of the java files generated under maven is target/classes (together with class files), which is far from perfect .

Answer (score 1):

According to [AndroidAnnotations Maven setup](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Maven), you don't need to do anything else, but to properly specify the dependencies, the plugin ... and that's it. You shouldn't care what maven puts in `target` basket as long as it properly generates the `apk` file.